# ASA 5505 HTTPS block

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Is it possible to block HTTPS websites with the ASA 5505?

I have conflicting information.

Answer (score 5):

Sorta... You *cannot* use the CSC modules on the ASA5505, all other ASA models can take that. It's  required to do real HTTPS inspection (and thus blocking). However, you could configure an ACL on the 'inside' interface that disallows traffic to port 443, which could effectively cut off most HTTPS traffic.

Comment: Would it be possible block a specific website or do I have to shut down 443?

Comment: You can block by destination IP as well. Since most websites don't change their IPs very often, it should work for a while. You'd have to keep an eye on it.